# C# Tabify/Indent HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex, indentation

Is there a tool/library/function in C# which tabifies or indents generated html code without validating or tidying the input?

Edit:

Indent generated HTML code from JavaScript TextEditors, including but not limited to TinyMCE. No HtmlTextWriter. Must not expect a valid XML/XHTML/HTML code.

Requirement:

- Add a new line before and after opening and closing tags.
- Indent content inside tags (Tab or 4 Spaces).
- Split a long line (having N number of words) into multiple indented lines.
- Do not change the input even though it is not a valid HTML. Only tabify/indent and split long lines.

Upto this point, I have:

```
private string FormatHtml(string input)
{
    //Opening tags
    Regex r = new Regex("<([a-z]+) *[^/]*?>");
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    retVal = r.Replace(input, string.Format("$&{0}\t", Environment.NewLine));

    //Closing tags
    r = new Regex("</[^>]*>");
    retVal = r.Replace(retVal, string.Format("{0}$&{0}", Environment.NewLine));

    //Self closing tags
    r = new Regex("<[^>/]*/>");
    retVal = r.Replace(retVal, string.Format("$&{0}", Environment.NewLine));

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input, and a sample of your expected output?

Comment: http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/ web-based, but provides C# source that you could integrate into another application.

Comment: That does not indent code at all. :)

Comment: _If_ the input HTML is also valid XML, you can use the XmlWriter with appropriate [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx).

Comment: If the HTML input is not valid, you'll have hard time to reindent it, as browsers will render invalid HTML the way they want. Whitespaces can be significant, especially in the case of malformed HTML. Anyway, you can use the HTML Agility Pack library at least to parse it. See here on SO for more on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 3):

You might want to rethink your approach, inserting newlines (and indenting) can cause serious white-space problems.

```
<span style="color:red">test</span><span>ing</span>
```

The html above does not display the same as the html you want to convert it to, there will be extra whitespace in the rendered html: `testing` vs `test ing`

```
<span style="color:red">
    test
</span>
<span>
    ing
</span>
```

You should only insert a newline if there is already whitespace present.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of a long winded way of doing it but its the only thing I can think of off the top of my head.

Use an sgml converter to convert the html to xml ie HtmlAgility or [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader)

You could then write out to an XmlTextWriter and specify in the settings that you want indents.

Comment: Instead of making any changes to the input, how could one only indent the contents inside html tags?

Comment: In that case, have you looked at HTML Tidy, http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ there is a .net binding available at http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931

Comment: The referenced library "libtidy.dll" crashes Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1  64 bit. Very unstable. :(

Comment: Still, when looking at the above link, it does not indent code, as well.

Comment: The documentation of Tidy html shows that it can indent code, http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/Overview.html so not sure what is going on there, as to the crash, the most likely cause is that the source is compiled against any source which I have had issues with in the past. Either set it to x86 or x64.